# How to get items present in the root of Dropbox using Dropbox HTTP API

Tags: c#, httprequest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using version 2 API of Dropbox. And to get list of files or folder present in a folder, I need to pass the path of the folder as input parameter. I need to get the list of all files and folders present at root level of Dropbox. So, what should I pass as path of the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent the root, pass an empty string.